# Collections removeAll method

Tags: java, collections

I would like to know if something like below is possible,

```
list.removeAll(namesToRemove)
```

I hope the context is understandable.

The `list` is of type `ArrayList<MyObject>` where `MyObject` has a `getName` method.

The `namesToRemove` is an `ArrayList<String>` containing names of the objects to be removed.

I know this can be achieved by overriding equals method in `MyObject` class.  I would like to know if any other choice is present.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. The list contains `MyObject`s. Why would you remove `String`s from it? There aren't any.

Comment: I'm trying to remove based on MyObject.getName()

Comment: Are you hoping to use List of strings as 'keys' to be removed from your list of 'MyObjects'?

Comment: Yeap, This I achieved by overriding equals method in MyObject class. I would like to go with another best approach because equals is restricted for me at the moment.

Comment: You could extend `ArrayList` and implement your own logic on the `removeAll` method. But yeah, removing list of Strings from a list of something totally different doesn't make sense conceptually.

Comment: how about using a map with getName() as keys? sounds like exactly what you want. And if you need a collection view, use map.values()

Comment: In Java 8+ you would use streams processing to do this. Simply define a predicate which checks to see if namesToRemove.contains(myObject.getName()) and a List collector. The main difference between AbstractList's removeAll implementation and the streams approach is that the streams approach will create a new list (which you can set the original reference back to) while the .removeAll will maintain the array in place (with lots of array copies if you are removing more than you are keeping).

Comment: @TomDibble, no need to use streams in Java 8. You can use [`Collection::removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) as demonstrated in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3005622/276052) below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this using [Google Collections](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/) [`Collections2.filter()`](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html#filter(java.util.Collection,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate)):

```
final List<String> namesToKeep = getNamesToFilter();
List<MyObject> filtered = Collections2.filter(originalList, new Predicate<MyObject>() {
  @Override
  public boolean apply(MyObject o) {
    return namesToKeep.contains(o.getName());
  }
});
```

Comment: formatting is broken. I would fix it but I don't have the rights yet. Also, google collections is deprecated. use guava instead: http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries

Comment: thanks, @seanizer. I hate that JavaDoc produces spaces in their link, but am not sure who to blame: Them for doing it or the SO software for not handling it ;-) I prefer to link Google Collections, because it has a final release, which Guava doesn't have yet (and switching from Google Collections to Guava is pretty easy anyway).

Comment: on my machine, firefox does it correctly (converting space to %20), while ie leaves the spaces. both fail, however, when it comes to converting parentheses to %28 and %29

Comment: Guava had a proper binary release on April 9 and has already had two more since then.  The newest is called version "5" since there were two "source releases" before all this.

Answer (score 4):

**Java 8:**

```
list.removeIf(obj -> namesToRemove.contains(obj.getName()));
```

**Java 7 and older:**

```
Iterator<MyObject> iter = list.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext())
    if (namesToRemove.contains(iter.next().getName()))
        iter.remove();
```

---

Note that both alternatives have quadratic complexity. You can make it linear by doing

```
Set<String> namesToRemoveSet = new HashSet<>(namesToRemove);
```

before the snippets, and use `namesToRemoveSet` instead of `namesToRemove`.

Comment: You'll have to do it with a loop (unless you accept 3rd party libs like google collections as Joachim mentioned above)

Comment: ... as does removeAll's implementation (loop over the source list). In fact, not much difference between the above code and the default ArrayList.removeAll(Collection<E> list) implementation, other than that the canonical implementation calls .equals instead of some function you wrote.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to override anything in the Object class. You need to use either [a filter utility](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html#filter%28java.util.Collection,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29) or a collection that uses your own semantics instead of equals, maybe a [ForwardingCollection](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingCollection.html) wrapped around your own implementation of [equivalence](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Equivalence.html).

All this can be achieved with [google guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries) without breaking any standards

Answer (score 0):

Another approach: Subclass `ArrayList` and implement a custom method like:

```
public class MyArrayList<E> extends ArrayList<E> {

   // all needed constructors

   public void removeAllWithNames(Collection<String> names) {
     // following code is based on aioobe's answer
     Iterator<E> iter = iterator();
       while (iter.hasNext())
         if (names.contains(iter.next().toString()))
           iter.remove();
   }
}
```

**EDIT**
changed the code - the comment was good, now the custom list is a 'List' again, but now we use the `toString()` method (for simplicity) for filtering. (using a `getName()` method is possible but requires more lines of code)

Comment: bad style, as it breaks the interface. unless you create an interface first that extends list and includes this method, but that's a bit like swatting flies with a Buick

Comment: @seanizer, in what sense does it "break the interface"?

Comment: @seanizer - If you'd argued 'bead style', because you should favour composition of inheritance, then I'd agreed. Like aioobe I have no clue which interface is broken. This is a customized Arraylist, limited to MyObject objects, nothing else.

Comment: it means that I have to code against this custom list, not against the list interface. This is a bad thing in itself, but it also breaks all kinds of wrapper / delegate methods e.g. in the java.util.Collections class

Comment: your edit doesn't really change anything, what I mean is: you have public methods that are not accessible from an interface. This is fine for pojos, but bad for collections. so you could do it like this: http://pastebin.com/ZKFkAE9s to fix that, but still you would be losing methods like Collections.synchronizedList() etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
Collection<MyObject> list = Collections2.filter(list, mo -> !namesToRemove.contains(mo.getName()));
```